# I am running MySQL query with \ in the where column and getting no results

Tags: c#, mysql, database, backslash

I am running the below MySQL query from c# code and the backlash is recognized only I enter it twice. Is it something I am missing in MYSQL database settings that's causing this

Not Working

```
SELECT * FROM user where username='B\asd';
```

Working

```
SELECT * FROM user where username='B\\asd';
```

But in the username column it is saved as 'B\asd'.

Do I need to charset or anything to make it work with single backsplash?

Comment: If your string contains a slash, you may need to escape it to ensure proper handling. In C#, the backslash () is used as an escape character, so if your string has a slash, you'll need to escape it by using a double backslash (\).

Comment: You should use `MySqlParameter` instead of a string literal in C#; this will prevent SQL injection and escape the string for you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MySqlParameter`, which will avoid SQL injection and also escape the string for you correctly:

```cs
using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user where username=@username;", yourConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", @"B\asd");
using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
// read data
```

Answer (score -1):

The backslash character (\) is used to escape characters or to create special ones like tabs (\t) and line breaks (\r and \n). This results in having to escape the character itself for it to be recognized as a part of the string in this case the SQL query.

In your example when using just a single backslash "\a" gets translated into an ASCII character with the hex value of 07

Comment: Not only in C# if I execute this query in MYSQL also it doesn't return any records but the same works in SQL and  c# code

Comment: That's because you also need to escape the character in MySQL, nothing weird about it